# configure: error: DRI3 requires xcb >= 1.9.3

Tags: mesa

I download Mesa and was trying to compile it:

```
sh ./autogen.sh 
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Autoheader
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --no-force
src/mesa/Makefile.sources:7: warning: BUILDDIR multiply defined in condition TRUE ...
src/mesa/Makefile.am:63:   'src/mesa/Makefile.sources' included from here
src/mesa/Makefile.am:62: ... 'BUILDDIR' previously defined here
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
xxxxx
xxxxx
checking for DRI3PROTO... yes
checking for PRESENTPROTO... yes
configure: error: DRI3 requires xcb >= 1.9.3
```

Not sure what is the error here?

I followed the conversation here:   https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80848

But still unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

You need libxcb (which requires xcb-proto) available here: http://xcb.freedesktop.org/dist/.

Build procedure is the same: ./autogen.sh; make; make install

Note that libxcb and xcb-proto require an up-to-date xorg-macros which you may not already have. That's available here: http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/xorg/util/macros.git/

Comment: will try your recommendation soon.

Comment: BTW, there are scripts that automate building X. Here's one that I've used successfully: http://www.x.org/wiki/Building_the_X_Window_System/

Answer (score 1):

Check your version with command:
pkg-config --modversion xcb
(thanks to Jan and Matt from bug reports). If response is 1.9 you need to find more recent version from http://xcb.freedesktop.org/dist/ and install it manually. I had version 1.9-5 installed from yum repositories and it was, in fact, 1.9 with some patches, not enough.

Comment: cool thanks for your solution...have not tried anything yet....setup already destroyed...will retry again soon.   thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. installed version is xcb 1.9-5. actually query for xcb version returns 1.9 and configure compares it to XCB_REQUIRED=1.9.3. I fixed configure: XCB_REQUIRED=1.9

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly be missing the package "libx11-xcb-dev" in debian systems install the package using the command sudo apt-get install libx11-xcb-dev

Answer (score 0):

You should try this `sudo apt-get install -y libxcb1-dev`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...it would be good if you could include some more detail on why this is the solution, what it does etc. I notice that there are other answers that refer to the same library...but you cannot rely on these answers remaining as is to give yours context.

Comment: Hi, @TimRadcliffe, as the command line and the package name "libxcb1-dev" is good enough to tell. The requirement for build it is in the package.